# update JSON file and determine group

Tags: php, json

With the help of you guys I learned how to utilize PHP to insert data in a simple JSON.

But what if the JSON contains multiple arrays? For example:

```
{
 "nodes": [
    { "id": 0, "type": "food"   },
    { "id": 1, "type": "drinks" },
    { "id": 2, "type": "snacks" }
 ],
 "links": [
    { "source": 0, "target": 1},
    { "source": 1, "target": 2},
    { "source": 2, "target": 0}
 ]
}
```

My PHP script only works for simple JSON files. I searched through the web to gather more information about my use case but it seems not that common. I need to specify there I want to append data. Currently the PHP receives an object which looks like `{"id": 3, "type": "drinks"}`.

How can I determine in which array ("nodes" or "links") I want to add data.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");


// This PHP receives a JSON object from type node.
// Example: {"id: 3, "type": "drinks"}

$data = ($_POST);

print_r($data);

$json = file_get_contents("data.json");
$tempArray = json_decode($json);

$tempArray[] = $data;
$jsonToEncode = json_encode($tempArray);

file_put_contents("data.json", $jsonToEncode)
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean `group`? Please explain this sentence _How can I determine in which "group" the object should be stored?_

Comment: The JSON I mentioned contains "nodes" .. and "links" .. now I want to add data only in "nodes". My question is, how can I define where I want to add data.

Comment: It would perhaps help if you stopped viewing this as “working with JSON” primarily. Your actual question/issue here is more about the _data objects_ encoded in that JSON. JSON is only a transport/storage format for this data. Now, what you have here on the outer level, is an _object_, not an array - so you would either need to use object property access syntax, `$tempArray->nodes` – or you would need to use the second parameter of json_decode, to get this transformed into an associative array, then it would be  `$tempArray['nodes']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can manipulate the json data in `nodes`:
You can see it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/D3vzyKFBT0cYPK4B

```
$json = '{
 "nodes": [
    { "id": 0, "type": "food"   },
    { "id": 1, "type": "drinks" },
    { "id": 2, "type": "snacks" }
 ],
 "links": [
    { "source": 0, "target": 1},
    { "source": 1, "target": 2},
    { "source": 2, "target": 0}
 ]
}';

$json = json_decode($json);
unset($json->nodes[1]);
echo(json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo "\n ------------------- \n";
$newdata = new stdClass;
$newdata->type="Cheeseburger";
$newdata->id=99;
$json->nodes[]=$newdata;

echo(json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```